# Why is the programm not inserting the value into the list?

Tags: list-manipulation

im new to mathematica and trying to learn the language, but i cant get this program to work. The program is not inserting i into the list and i get the error message

> Insert::ins: Cannot insert at position {1,2} in {{}}.

This happens the in the second loop because it didn't insert anything in the first.
Thanks for any help in advance!!
Here is the code:

```
myDo[v_ ] := Module[ {list = {3, 4, 5, 8, 8}, lis2 = {{}}, nr2 = 1, nr1 = 1},
    Do[
    n = list[[i]];
    If[v - n < 2, If[v - n > -2,
     Insert[lis2, i, {nr1, nr2}];
     nr2++]];
   , {i, 1, Length[list]}];]`
```

Comment: Almost never use `Do`.  Instead, use `Table`.

Comment: can you post the desired results for, say, `myDo[1]`, `myDo[2]`, `myDo[3]`, `myD[10]`?

Comment: does this give the desired results: `myDo2[v_] := 
 Module[{list = {3, 4, 5, 8, 8}, lis2 = {{}}, nr2 = 1, nr1 = 1}, 
  Do[n = list[[i]];  If[Abs[v - n] < 2, lis2 = Insert[lis2, i, List /@ {nr1, nr2}];
    nr2++], {i, 1, Length[list]}]; lis2]`?

Comment: I want to find out wich numbers are close to the one i put in so for myDo[1] it would be an empyty list for myDo[2] it would have a 1 in it because the first nr(3) in the list is next to it for myDo[3] i would be 1 and 2 in a list. But this is just a small sample size for a test the size of the list would later be larger and the Distance could be larger too.

Comment: ur solution also gives me the error message: Insert::ins: Cannot insert at position {1,2} in {{}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[myDo2]
myDo2[v_] := Module[{list = {3, 4, 5, 8, 8}, lis2 = {{}}, nr2 = 1, nr1 = 1}, 
    Do[n = list[[i]];
    If[Abs[v - n] < 2, lis2 = Insert[lis2, i, {nr1, nr2++}]], {i, 1, Length[list]}]; lis2]
myDo2 /@ Range[10]
```

> {{{}}, {{1}}, {{1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 3}}, {{2, 3}}, {{3}}, {{4, 5}}, {{4, 
>      5}}, {{4, 5}}, {{}}}

An alternative way to generate the same output using [`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Module[{a = If[Head@#2 === List, List, Identity], b}, 
    b = a /. {List -> Identity, Identity -> List};
     a /@ Sort /@ Nearest[# -> "Index", b[#2], {All, 2 - $MachineEpsilon}]] & ;

lst = {3, 4, 5, 8, 8} ;
f[lst, #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

> {{{}}, {{1}}, {{1, 2}}}

```
f[lst, {1,2,3}]
```

> {{{}}, {{1}}, {{1, 2}}}

```
f[lst, Range[10]] == myDo2 /@ Range[10]
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

The statement from your code

```
Insert[lis2, i, {nr1, nr2}];
```

produces a list but leaves `lis2` **unchanged!**

This was the source of the error message in your code (occurs on the second iteration).

You need to set `lis2` equal to the output of the `Insert` function

```
lis2 = Insert[lis2, i, {nr1, nr2}];
```

in your code.

Further, in order to see the result, you need the expression `lis2` at the end of the `Module`.

```
myDo[v_] := Module[{
   list = {3, 4, 5, 8, 8},
   lis2 = {{}},
   nr2 = 1,
   nr1 = 1
   },
  Do[n = list[[i]];
    If[v - n < 2,
     If[v - n > -2,
      lis2 = Insert[lis2, i, {nr1, nr2}];
      nr2++
      ]
     ];,
    {i, 1, Length[list]}
    ];
    lis2
  ]

myDo[7]
(* {{4, 5}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I did the same with Table. I am not sure why double brackets are needed in the final result (and the list definitions do not need to be in the Module). I am sure the syntax can be greatly simplified, but it works. Building on the previous answer,

Setting initial elements, for v data

```
list = {3, 4, 5, 8, 8}; nr1 = 1; v = Range[10];
```

This produces a matrix where the needed results are the columns.

```
res = Table[lis2 = {{}}; nr2 = 1; 
If[Abs[v[[j]] - list[[i]]] < 2, 
lis2 = Insert[lis2, i, {1, nr2++}], {}], {i, 1, Length[list]}, {j,
 1, Length[v]}];

MatrixForm[res]
```

[image: Output]

To get the output one needs to join the elements in each column. I found two ways to do that, one with Table and one with Map, depending on the length of data v.

```
(*Either*)
Table[Flatten[res[[All, i]]], {i, 1, Length[v]}]
(*or*)
Flatten[res[[All, #]]] & /@ Range[Length[v]]
```